# What is the difference between double() and float() methods in migraions in Yii2?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

When you create a migration in Yii2 you can use:

```
$this->addColumn('table_a', 'value', $this->float()->null());
```

or

```
$this->addColumn('table_a', 'value', $this->double()->null());
```

But the result in Postgres is the same type: double precision.

Is there a difference?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: I understand the difference in postgres, I am interested in Yii2. Yii has two methods that do the same. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do exactly the same.

Let's take a look at [implementation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/ae82b58d856c2e8c17468d0b2de41a4fb9c17d2b/framework/db/SchemaBuilderTrait.php#L155) of these methods:

```php
public function float($precision = null)
{
    return $this->getDb()->getSchema()->createColumnSchemaBuilder(Schema::TYPE_FLOAT, $precision);
}

public function double($precision = null)
{
    return $this->getDb()->getSchema()->createColumnSchemaBuilder(Schema::TYPE_DOUBLE, $precision);
}
```

As you can see both methods uses different constant for creation of `ColumnSchemaBuilder` instance. The [value](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/ae82b58d856c2e8c17468d0b2de41a4fb9c17d2b/framework/db/Schema.php#L57) of constants is also different.

```php
const TYPE_FLOAT = 'float';
const TYPE_DOUBLE = 'double';
```

So why is the result same for Postgres? The reason is in [`yii\db\pgsql\QueryBuilder`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/ae82b58d856c2e8c17468d0b2de41a4fb9c17d2b/framework/db/pgsql/QueryBuilder.php#L67) which maps both abstract types to same final type.

```php
public $typeMap = [
    // ...
    Schema::TYPE_FLOAT => 'double precision',
    Schema::TYPE_DOUBLE => 'double precision',
    // ...
];
```

It's done this way because of abstraction. It allows you to write the migrations that will work no matter if the application runs on Postgres, MySQL or MSSQL.

But, I don't know why the authors of framework decided to map both abstract types to `double precision`.